# Need to generate API key for different application

Tags: api-key

I have developed API in dot net. This API is consumed by different application. I have to generate a different key for each application which is consumed by this API. Can anyone please share their Ideas. This is first time i am doing such tasks.

Answer (score 2):

## Your Problem

> I have developed API in dot net. This API is consumed by different application. I have to generate a different key for each application which is consumed by this API.

When creating an API, no matter if consumed by one or more applications you need to deal with the fact of **WHAT** is accessing the API and sometimes you also need to care about **WHO** is accessing it.

With this in mind lets clear a common misconception among developers about **WHO** and **WHAT** is accessing an API server.

## The Difference Between WHO and WHAT is Accessing the API Server

I don't know if the applications consuming the API are mobile or web based, but I will do my analogy using a mobile application, and for a web application the difference between **WHO** and **WHAT** will make no difference.

To better understand the differences between the **WHO** and the **WHAT** are accessing a mobile app, let’s use this picture:

[image: Man in the Middle Attack]

The Intended Communication Channel represents the mobile app being used as you expected, by a legit user without any malicious intentions, using an untampered version of the mobile app, and communicating directly with the API server without being man in the middle attacked.

The actual channel may represent several different scenarios, like a legit user with malicious intentions that may be using a repackaged version of the mobile app, a hacker using the genuine version of the mobile app, while man in the middle attacking it, to understand how the communication between the mobile app and the API server is being done in order to be able to automate attacks against your API. Many other scenarios are possible, but we will not enumerate each one here.

I hope that by now you may already have a clue why the **WHO** and the **WHAT** are not the same, but if not it will become clear in a moment.

The **WHO** is the user of the mobile app that we can authenticate, authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID Connect or OAUTH2 flows.

> [OAUTH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)
>
> Generally, OAuth provides to clients a "secure delegated access" to server resources on behalf of a resource owner. It specifies a process for resource owners to authorize third-party access to their server resources without sharing their credentials. Designed specifically to work with Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP), OAuth essentially allows access tokens to be issued to third-party clients by an authorization server, with the approval of the resource owner. The third party then uses the access token to access the protected resources hosted by the resource server.
>
> [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/)
>
> OpenID Connect 1.0 is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol. It allows Clients to verify the identity of the End-User based on the authentication performed by an Authorization Server, as well as to obtain basic profile information about the End-User in an interoperable and REST-like manner.

While user authentication may let the API server know **WHO** is using the API, it cannot guarantee that the requests have originated from **WHAT** you expect, the original version of the mobile app.

Now we need a way to identify **WHAT** is calling the API server, and here things become more tricky than most developers may think. The **WHAT** is the thing making the request to the API server. Is it really a genuine instance of the mobile app, or is a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around with the API server, using a tool like Postman?

For your surprise you may end up discovering that It can be one of the legit users using a repackaged version of the mobile app or an automated script that is trying to gamify and take advantage of the service provided by the application.

Well, to identify the **WHAT**, developers tend to resort to an API key that usually they hard-code in the code of their mobile app. Some developers go the extra mile and compute the key at run-time in the mobile app, thus it becomes a runtime secret as opposed to the former approach when a static secret is embedded in the code.

The above write-up was extracted from an article I wrote, entitled *WHY DOES YOUR MOBILE APP NEED AN API KEY?*, and that you can read in full [here](https://blog.approov.io/why-does-your-mobile-app-need-an-api-key), that is the first article in a series of articles about API keys.

## Defending an API Server

> Can anyone please share their Ideas.

A mobile app or a web app should only communicate with a API server that is under your control and any access to third part APIs services must be done by this same API server you control.

This way you limit the attack surface to only one place, where you will employ as many layers of defense as what you are protecting is worth.

For an API serving a web app you can employ several layers of dense, starting with [reCaptcha V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html), followed by [Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall)(WAF) and finally if you can afford it a [User Behavior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics)(UBA) solution.

Google [reCAPTCHA V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html):

> reCAPTCHA is a free service that protects your website from spam and abuse. reCAPTCHA uses an advanced risk analysis engine and adaptive challenges to keep automated software from engaging in abusive activities on your site. It does this while letting your valid users pass through with ease.
>
> ...helps you detect abusive traffic on your website without any user friction. It returns a score based on the interactions with your website and provides you more flexibility to take appropriate actions.

[WAF - Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall):

> A web application firewall (or WAF) filters, monitors, and blocks HTTP traffic to and from a web application. A WAF is differentiated from a regular firewall in that a WAF is able to filter the content of specific web applications while regular firewalls serve as a safety gate between servers. By inspecting HTTP traffic, it can prevent attacks stemming from web application security flaws, such as SQL injection, cross-site scripting (XSS), file inclusion, and security misconfigurations.

[UBA - User Behavior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics):

> User behavior analytics (UBA) as defined by Gartner is a cybersecurity process about detection of insider threats, targeted attacks, and financial fraud. UBA solutions look at patterns of human behavior, and then apply algorithms and statistical analysis to detect meaningful anomalies from those patterns—anomalies that indicate potential threats. Instead of tracking devices or security events, UBA tracks a system's users. Big data platforms like Apache Hadoop are increasing UBA functionality by allowing them to analyze petabytes worth of data to detect insider threats and advanced persistent threats.

All this solutions work based on a negative identification model, by other words they try their best to differentiate the bad from the good by identifying what is bad, not what is good, thus they are prone to false positives, despite of the advanced technology used by some of them, like machine learning and artificial intelligence.

So you may find yourself more often than not in having to relax how you block the access to the API server in order to not affect the good users. This also means that this solutions require constant monitoring to validate that the false positives are not blocking your legit users and that at same time they are properly keeping at bay the unauthorized ones.

Regarding APIs serving mobile apps a positive identification model can be used by using a Mobile App Attestation solution that guarantees to the API server that the requests can be trusted without the possibility of false positives.

#### The Mobile App Attestation

The role of a Mobile App Attestation service is to guarantee at run-time that your mobile app was not tampered or is not running in a rooted device by running a SDK in the background that will communicate with a service running in the cloud to attest the integrity of the mobile app and device is running on.

On successful attestation of the mobile app integrity a short time lived JWT token is issued and signed with a secret that only the API server and the Mobile App Attestation service in the cloud are aware. In the case of failure on the mobile app attestation the JWT token is signed with a secret that the API server does not know.

Now the App must sent with every API call the JWT token in the headers of the request. This will allow the API server to only serve requests when it can verify the signature and expiration time in the JWT token and refuse them when it fails the verification.

Once the secret used by the Mobile App Attestation service is not known by the mobile app, is not possible to reverse engineer it at run-time even when the App is tampered, running in a rooted device or communicating over a connection that is being the target of a Man in the Middle Attack.

The Mobile App Attestation service already exists as a SAAS solution at [Approov](https://www.approov.io/approov-in-detail.html)(I work here) that provides SDKs for several platforms, including iOS, Android, React Native and others. The integration will also need a small check in the API server code to verify the JWT token issued by the cloud service. This check is necessary for the API server to be able to decide what requests to serve and what ones to deny.

## Summary

I think it should be pretty clear by now that you will need to use an API key for each application to identify the **WHAT**, and if you care about the **WHO** you should employ an OAUTH solution to, and then choose what defense layers you want to put in place on the API server to guarantee that you really know that the **WHAT** and the **WHO** is accessing the API server are really the ones you expect.

In the end the solution to use in order to protect your API server must be chosen in accordance with the value of what you are trying to protect and the legal requirements for that type of data, like the GDPR regulations in Europe.

So using API keys may sound like locking the door of your home and leave the key under the mat, but not using them is liking leaving your car parked with the door closed, but the key in the ignition.

## Going the Extra Mile

> This is first time i am doing such tasks.

So I real recommend you to read some links...

#### Web Apps

[OWASP Web Top 10 Risks](https://www.owasp.org/images/7/72/OWASP_Top_10-2017_%28en%29.pdf.pdf)

> The OWASP Top 10 is a powerful awareness document for web application security. It represents a broad consensus about the most critical security risks to web applications. Project members include a variety of security experts from around the world who have shared their expertise to produce this list.

#### Mobile Apps

[OWASP Mobile Security Project - Top 10 risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#Top_Ten_Mobile_Risks)

> The OWASP Mobile Security Project is a centralized resource intended to give developers and security teams the resources they need to build and maintain secure mobile applications. Through the project, our goal is to classify mobile security risks and provide developmental controls to reduce their impact or likelihood of exploitation.